# Retain only records whose belongs_to association's has_many has a COUNT of 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

This question is easy to understand with an example: like airbnb, guest reviews a host and host reviews a guest. The Booking has exactly 2 reviews (both created when the booking is created), and reviews have a field `submitted: true/false`

Suppose we wish to display a host's reviews on their profile, but suppose we want to *exclude* any reviews for which the host hasn't yet reviewed the guest. (so even if the guest has reviewed the host, it shouldn't be displayed until the host has reciprocated and reviewed the guest). How can we do it?

Also a Booking has_many Reviews, and Reviews are polymorphic on Host and Guest.

#### What I know so far

I've come up with all sorts of half-solutions that either don't work, or result it awfully inefficient sql. Here's one

```rb
bookings_for_host = Booking.where(host_id: 1).pluck(:id) # use host number 1 here for example
all_reviews_for_relevant_bookings = Review.where('booking_id IN (?)', bookings_for_host)

# This doesn't work
all_reviews_for_relevant_bookings
  .select("booking_id")
  .group("booking_id")
  .having("COUNT(booking_id = 2")
```

The above code not only doesn't work, but it would also be inefficient.

#### Question

Ultimately, how could I filter a host's reviews so as to not include reviews that belong_to an Booking that has less than 2 reviews that have `submitted == true` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 possible solution for this

**Solution 1** : **Adding a boolean value to your review table** (**I personally would have chosen this one**)

You can add a boolean column say `host_and_guest_reviewed` to your `bookings` table which you can update when both `host` and `guest` reviews has been created. Then all you will have to do is to check if this value is true. The boolean column might be on reviews table as well depending on you requirement.

**Solution 2** : **Using a counter cache**

Every time a review is created against a booking, the counter on the booking will increase. In this case you can efficiently weed out bookings which don't have 2 reviews

You can read more about counter cache [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

**Solution 3** : **Self join SQL query**

You can join the reviews table on itself so that only the reviews with another review for the booking get included. Something like this

```
Review
  .joins('INNER JOINS reviews reciprocated_reviews ON reviews.id != reciprocated_reviews.id AND reviews.booking_id = reciprocated_reviews.booking_id')
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Can I ask why you would use Solution 1 over Solution 3? Is it because it's simpler? I think 3 might be better because it keeps business logic and data layer separate?

Comment: Because the query in `solution 3` is comparitively expensive. You can do an `explain` on the query generated and check that the database server has to actually go through each and every row within the table to perform the `reviews.id != reciprocated_reviews.id` part. I might be wrong on this one, you should verify it once.